# how to use common WHERE parameter for all models in EF by LINQ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

The system has several classes of model (eg, tasks, invoices, reports). For each table, depending on the logged company by some parameter(eg. companyID). And I must for every table, every query, every saving, etc. watch this parameter. Is there a simpler way to tell EF to LINQ to each query add this parameter? In other words, if I enter just:

```
List<Report> list = db.Reports;
```

that were selected only relevant records with companyID of logged company like

```
List<Report> list = db.Reports.Where(r => r.companyID = idOfLoggedComp)
```

Thanks a lot for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is no. EF is completely missing global filters. You must make some wrapper class and hide the query inside custom exposed `IQueryable` like:

```
public class CompanyRestrictedDataAccess
{
    private int _companyId;
    private ObjectContext _context;

    public CompanyDataAccess(int companyId, ObjectContext context)
    {
        _companyId = companyId;
        _context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Reports> Reports
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Reports.Where(r => r.CompanyId == _companyId); 
        }
    }
}
```

But this is still very poor workaround because:

- You must use this class for queries instead of context
- It works only for direct access. Eager loading and lazy loading completely ignores any conditions (eager and lazy loading in EF even cannot be filtered).

So you must correctly handle your loading in the application.

The only solution which EF provides is called Conditional mapping but it is hardcoded single filtering condition directly in EDMX so your application would work only for single company.

Answer (score 0):

If you have FKs in your tables pointing to ID field on company table then you should be able to filter all your related tables by simply accessing those via your "company" table in the context, like this:

```
List<Report> list = db.Company.Reports;
```

Without much hassle.

Or, if you don't have your *company* in context yet:

```
var company = db.FirstOrDefault( c => c.ID == companyId );
List<Report> list = company.Reports;
```

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't support this by default but there are some design patterns which can help.

Especially the Criteria pattern in combination with a repository. [This article](http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=249) is a good read
.

It explains how to build criteria and combine them (trough a decorator pattern). If you would add your filter to the base criteria class you could make sure that it's added to all queries.

Filtering Included navigational data is a lot harder as Ladislav pointed out. You could use an Expression Visitor to alter your query or use the base Criteria class to do an Linq To Objects filter (which is easier to implement) but that means that you will load the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this will help you. You can do something like this.

```
string whereClause = "";

if(cId > 0)
{
whereClause += "it.companyID =@companyID && "

ob.Add(New ObjectParameter("companyID", cId));

}
```

// You can add other parameters using more if conditions..

```
whereClause  = whereClause.Remove(whereClause.Length, -3);

qry = dEntity.Reports.Where(whereClause, ob.ToArray);
```